# Identifying homeomorhisms

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let
$$
A = [0,1]\times [0,1)\\
B = [0,1)\times [0,1)\\
C = [0,1]\times (0,1) \\
D = [0,1)\times (0,1)
$$
 In the above examples which sets are homeomorphic? I know $C$ is not homeomorphic to $D$. I can identify homeomorphisms quite well in R ( same kind of intervals are homeomorphic), but in higher dimensions what is the criteria, when the sets are connected? 
I am talking about a method of identifying homemorphisms without explicit formula to get an idea about the topic.

Comment: I got it. bounded Connected intervals with same kind of boundary are homeomorphic. So A,C,D are homemorphic. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: My guess would be that A, B and D are homeomorphic because their "boundaries have one component" but C is not homeomorphic to the others because its boundary has two components. You can probably show that A, B and D are homeomorphic by writing explicit homeomorphisms. But I can't think of a rigorous argument for why C is not homeomorphic to the rest. The difficulty is that the "boundary" is not an intrinsically defined concept; it is only defined in relation to how you embed your sets into $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Sorry I meant A,B,D

Comment: Here's an idea: for metric spaces, there is a notion of a "completion". I have never studied this, but I presume taking the completion of one of your spaces adds in the missing "boundary points". Maybe you can try to distinguish the spaces by whether the completion minus the original space is connected or disconnected. I'm not too sure though.

Comment: @KennyWong Boundary can be defined independently of where those spaces are embedded in, i.e. all of them are manifolds with boundary. And indeed every homeomorphism has to map boundary to boundary and that's why $C$ is not heomomoprhic to others: it has a disconnected boundary (in the manifold sense). This doesn't help much in other cases though. I've tried to find some properties of boundaries that would help to construct such homeomorphism but I've failed horribly. I think that explicit homeomorphisms is the way to go.

Comment: @freakish Thanks for telling me! Can I define it by saying that a point $p$ is a boundary point iff there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ that is homeomorphic to the closed half-plane?

Comment: @KennyWong Yes, exactly. This doesn't work well for smooth manifolds (because the cube has "corners") but it works for topological manifolds.